# Any way to replicate pigment theory in blender?

Tags: node-editor

I have blue and yellow on a color ramp, but they mix to make white. I know that this is because blender follows light theory, where blue and yellow make white, red, blue, and green are primaries, and magenta and cyan exist, but how would I make it follow the standards of pigment color theory, where blue and yellow make green?

[image]

Notice how white is in the middle rather than green.

Comment: I would suggest some configuration of inverting the colors first, since pigment works by subtracting.

Comment: Could you explain more? How would I do this?

Comment: It’s a math problem, and will probably somewhat depend on what you were trying to do, but basically, paint absorbs light, and that is why mixing two colors of paint does not produce the same affect as mixing two colors of light.

Comment: The main reason why mixing pure red and pure blue paint does not then produce black is that mixtures of different frequencies and look like pure red frequency to our eyes. This is what makes color television possible.

Comment: I know this. But how would I go about doing this? Blue and yellow as inverted colors just gives me - well - yellow and blue, because blue and yellow are compliments in light theory. I like knowing the science behind it, but how would I put what you are saying into blender to get blue+yellow=green. (In my case it is actually I want green and blue to blend and not make cyan, but the blue+yellow thing is more well known)

Comment: Aha! It’s not blue and yellow, it’s cyan and yellow.

Comment: Just tell me how to do it please. I appreciate that you are giving me the science, but I want an answer as well.

Comment: Question: do you need a gradient?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to replicate a colorwheel, so I need a gradient. The gradient is the main problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a beta set up that seems to work.
[image: node group]
[image: initial results]
[image: gradient usage]

Comment: Nice! does this work with all colors, or just these 2?

Comment: It’s not been tested fully, but if you want to volunteer, it is designed for such.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in my case. I put the blend file in, if you want you could see how to get rid of the cyan. Thanks for the effort though     [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=b1voO66w" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/b1voO66w/)

Comment: You know I was not using regular RGB color mix, right? I was using my own node group.

Comment: Yes, I replicated that node group, yet it didn't work

Comment: Are you sure you replicated it correctly? The names are a little fuzzy. The three math nodes are all “minimum.”

Comment: Yes, I got 2 separate RGB nodes, plugged both R's into a minimum, both G's into a minimum, and both B's into a minimum, and put it back together with a combine rgb, but it gives a strange result

Comment: I’ll try to get the blind file sometime. I’m on mobile right now